# Loki MakeTypelist recursive template make me confuse

Tags: c++

I'm studying loki source code. below is the `MakeTypelist` which makes me confused.

```
class NullType {};
template <class T, class U>

struct Typelist
{
    typedef T Head;
     typedef U Tail;
};
template
<
typename T1  = NullType, typename T2  = NullType, typename T3  = NullType,
typename T4  = NullType, typename T5  = NullType, typename T6  = NullType,
typename T7  = NullType, typename T8  = NullType, typename T9  = NullType,
typename T10 = NullType, typename T11 = NullType, typename T12 = NullType,
typename T13 = NullType, typename T14 = NullType, typename T15 = NullType,
typename T16 = NullType, typename T17 = NullType, typename T18 = NullType
 > 
struct MakeTypelist
{
private:
 typedef typename MakeTypelist
 <
  T2 , T3 , T4 , 
  T5 , T6 , T7 , 
  T8 , T9 , T10, 
  T11, T12, T13,
  T14, T15, T16, 
  T17, T18
 >
  ::Result TailResult;

public:
  typedef Typelist<T1, TailResult> Result;
};

template<>
struct MakeTypelist<>
{
  typedef NullType Result;
};

using MyType=MakeTypeList<int, unsigned int, long, unsigned long, float>
```

How does the recursive template terminate?

it could not match empty type version `MakeTypelist`,
in the end it will match `MakeTypelist<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType .....>` ?

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct because `template<> struct MakeTypelist<> ...` will still use the default template arguments of NullType, so it is equivalent to `template<> struct MakeTypelist<NullType, NullType, ...>`. However, I can't find documentation to prove this which is why I'm not posting an answer :)

Comment: Loki have test, and the code is correct.

Comment: Notice that C++11 and variadic template supersedes `TypeList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive template will terminate due to specialization `template<> struct MakeTypelist<>` being defined which returns `NullType` value of `Result`.

This specialization is totally equal to next variant of code

```
template<>
struct MakeTypelist<NullType, NullType, NullType, NullType, ..... /* ... 18 Times ... */>
// .......
```

Because if not all or none template params are provided then all non-provided template params are considered to be equal to default values i.e. to `= NullType` (see main template definition, it has all 18 arguments-types having default `= NullType`).

This choosing of default arguments for those template params that are not provided has same logic like in using functions with default arguments, e.g. if you have function like `void f(int a = 0, int b = 0)` then you may call it three different ways `f()` and `f(0)` and `f(0, 0)` and all will give same results. And those function arguments that are not provided will be taken equal to defaults. Same is here in template specialization - if you don't provide any arguments i.e. write `struct MakeTuplelist<>` then all 18 arguments-types will be considered to be `NullType` because all 18 arguments have defaults `= NullType`, same behaviour like in function with default arguments example above.

Also in specialization you may provide just some of template arguments, the rest will be considered to be equal to defaults, e.g. `template<> struct MakeTypelist<int, bool>` specialization will be totally same as specialization `template<> struct MakeTypelist<int, bool, NullType, NullType, ...... /* 16 NullTypes */>`.

And recursion terminates because very last tail is equal to `MakeTypelist<NullType, NullType, NullType, .....>` which matches specialized version of `MakeTypelist` which cuts recursion by providing `NullType` value for `Result`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLbsIwELz7K/bYSq5EgDwgIede6KEKH@AGE1k1JkrsSiji21NvAmmQuhwWz8zuZBVPyrp@K7UwVd/7v7aFD6d1ca0ldLeUWXmutbASslEsOIyHQ85YaxtXWsBmrVrLOgb@Zz08yhMU8C7FMR24iTxAIZRO2cyaZQxVI84SigBgN23A4U9YUsLqSZhZramJkBIiyiqmJhJK2FBWwYKYCAJKWFJWK2piTQkhZRVREzElJDOBQQ6PNOzFt5wlom7Uj7/kLZsiMHk8dULmg@JvmeONcrw9DsiECCIs8Z1JEGywBIuRCQIESywrPhBrPIdYontLjCDxi3q03X7K1mk7ZHE8pozV7kur0i/6l@D7clmBD5h6c3jM@BRPMc7y/96AZ7uZ4/RtzR1cq0wF@ysKu6dhZSwHZ1pVGXmEAemLqWbcCE/6ImzurXwLnIUyL6/QQSOtawwsUrj1/S8)

PS. Same defaults-behavior is applied not only to specialization of template, but also to usage, you may use template like `typedef MakeTypelist<> T;` or `typedef MakeTypelist<int, bool> T;` in both cases the rest of 18 template arguments-types will become equal to defaults `= NullType`.

Comment: "template<> struct MakeTypeList<>" equal to "template <> struct MakeTypeList<NullType, NullType. ,,,,,>", I could not understand,  does C++ have rule for this ?

Comment: @yuandaxing Yes, exactly, if some of template arguments are not provided like here `struct MakeTypeList<>` where none arguments are provided, then template arguments are considered to be equal to default values i.e. values `= NullType` provided at main template definition. So basically you may either write template specialization with `struct MakeTypeList<NullType, NullType. ,,,,,>` or with just `MakeTypeList<>` both will give same result! Or you may just provide 1 or 2 arguments like this `struct MakeTypeList<NullType, NullType>` the rest is taken from defaults, and defaults are `= NullType`.

Comment: @yuandaxing It is same like calling a function with default arguments, if your function is defined like `void f(int a, int b = 12, int c = 34)` then you may call it like `f(8)` or `f(8, 12)` or `f(8, 12, 34)` and all will give same result as long as you  provide values equal to default arguments, those values that are not provided are considered to be equal defaults of `b` and `c`.

Comment: great explanation

Comment: @yuandaxing Also you're not restricted to providing none or all arguments, you may also provide just some arguments, e.g. `template<> struct MakeTypelist<int, bool>` specialization will be totally same as specialization `template<> struct MakeTypelist<int, bool, NullType, NullType, ...... /* 16 NullTypes */>`

Comment: @yuandaxing Same defaults-behavior is applied not only to specialization of template, but also to usage, you may use template like `typedef MakeTypelist<> T;` or `typedef MakeTypelist<int, bool> T;` in both cases the rest of 18 template arguments-types will become equal to defaults `= NullType`.